# Can't install quip apps from AppExchange

Tags: quip, liveapps

I've developed few quip live apps and submitted those to AppExchange. I followed this article

https://www.quipsupport.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002102492-Publish-Quip-Live-Apps-on-the-Salesforce-AppExchange

Following apps has already gone through security review and business plan has already been approved by Salesforce.

1. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FAa15UAD

   [Security Review and Business Plan Screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA1mE.png)
2. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EtEvdUAF
3. https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FZsy7UAD

If you open any app from above link and click "Get It Now" then you will need to login to your quip account (if not already) after that it gives "400 Bad Request"

[400 Bad Request Error.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5muJs.png)

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Quip apps has been developed using enterprise quip account (https://astreait.quip.com/).